# Curl argument list is too long error

Tags: curl

I have a very long curl command to trigger in terminal,

However, I'm hitting an error,

> "argument list is too long"

This is the sample query, I'm replacing the very long argument around 6MB(if I save it to a file) with the word "very long parameters":

> curl -H "Authorization:Bearer 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.eyJpc3MiOiJjb20uaWJtLm1mcCIsInN1YiI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXVkIjoiY29tLmlibS5tZnAiLCJleHAiOjE0ODQwMzA1OTM2MDAsInNjb3BlIjoiREVGQVVMVF9TQ09QRSJ9.QDgYUHYTHp6WfPQj3TcpM3uuiPWG92Jm4ovuf1f_N27wzfnmvYzYpGerB09oLrjisboXhczN17H4in8Kx69kKCM-L80i5JovSsUehH7aryPc195wNiHp5HC4V856I1cDSf7A7tALiz0xdKWmAlk1gFBfcFFdtfbR1cIeXjS_KGht9jaNbNwapTy0nrtmWGMr_s-nJo2p-FRLXb-NnbmpQG85BXptbBuPQCn4qXtHPRz61y9BWA6AgNpuTz9rVJyYux9yrtf9ONZtQ_GHWCJBe87Zm8bQLdDaMrCZKOnuVMT_upROfEaFvKwhdlWIM-CSY2whfe1yS3mv8AHBx11OtQ"
>   "http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/adapters/sendtextandPDF?params=[**very long parameters**]"
>   -g

How to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing this error is because your operating system kernel puts a limit on the arguments that can be passed to a command.  You can get around it by putting the URL in a configuration file, say `config` with a line such as the following

```
url = "http://localhost:9080/mfp/api/adapters/sendtextandPDF?params=[very long parameters]"
```

Then, run *curl* to fetch data from that URL by specifying the name of the configuration file as an argument:

```
curl -K config -g
```

Attempting to pass 6MB of data through a *GET* request is playing with fire. Several parts of the web stack may balk at this size. You encountered a problem with *curl*, but you could also face problems with an intermediate proxy, a load balancer, an application server, the web request parsing library, and the application itself. Instead, consider passing the data using a *PUSH* request, which is better designed to handle large transfers.

Comment: where should i pass in the "[very long parameters]"?

Comment: In the configuration file where you specify the URL.  I'm editing the answer to clarify.

Comment: where to add the -g flag?

Comment: That is likely to be a problem at the server end. For example, the application server may also have limits regarding the length of a GET request, so the actual request mey not reach your application. See comment at the end of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you pipe in to curl from text file?

```
cat textfile.txt | curl
```

Add your flags to curl and you should be good to go.

Also you might find this link useful. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174350/curl-argument-list-too-long

Comment: the link is passing in json... could you explain on how to pass in the parameters?